# How to automate cleaning of data in AWS using Jupyter Notebook

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, aws-glue, amazon-sagemaker

I have a Jupyter Notebook file that cleans the data file (.csv) in S3. The cleaning process is taken care of...

However, I want to be able to automatically apply this cleaning process to every file that is uploaded to the S3 bucket. Each file will have the exact same data format. I am thinking maybe of using AWS Glue, but not sure where to start. If we can skip the upload to S3 and go straight into Glue that would be interesting to explore...

The end goal is to load the clean data in Quick Sight and also AWS Sage Maker for ML applications.

Any advice on how to approach this?

Thanks

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details. You haven't even provided what programming language do you use, how big are the files, how many, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A simple AWS Lambda function with an [AWS EventBridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-what-is.html) Rule can do this. Check out this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html

Use the above link to set up the cron or event(whatever is your use case), write you s3 clean up code in lambda function. Lambda support multiple programming languages. And then let the lambda take care of it.